# Customize iCarousel ItemForView by setting its frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icarousel

Usually items of iCarousel are displayed downside tilted. I want the change with upside tilted.

I got the code at [github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)
and the iCarousel with options was nearest to my requirement.But it was for in same Y level Where I need to tilt it upwards.I changed its angle but it gets overlapped which is also not required. I simply just want to tilt the views upwards rather than downwards.

I have adjust `tilt` and `spacing` value of `converflow` type of iCarousel

Is there any idea to acquire this?

UPDATE:

I tried to use Cylindrical type in the example.And that matches the tilt effect upward as i want. But if I decrease the space it all overlaps and images are getting overlapped. Which I don't want I want images to get behind of each other

Comment: Did you mean "Options demo" project in example folder?

Comment: A picture of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: @PiyushDubey yes I am talking about "Options Demo"